# javascript help; pausing autorefresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, scroll, refresh

trying to figure a way to keep my chat div area from refreshing and annoyingly scrolling to the bottom. after searching the only solution I could come up with, is setting a global to a certain value and changing it when onfocus and back with onblur.

javascript was never my strongest area and I think it might just be me.

```
var chatarea = document.getElementById('usertalk');

window.onload=  function() {
    chatarea.scrollTop = chatarea.scrollHeight;
}

var chatfocus = false;


chatarea.onfocus=function(){ chatfocus = true; }

chatarea.onblur=function(){ chatfocus = false; }

setInterval("updateChat()", 5000);

function updateChat(){
    var ajaxRequest;
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                if(chatfocus === false){ 
                    chatarea.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                    chatarea.scrollTop = chatarea.scrollHeight; 
                }
            }
    }
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "comments.php?t=<?php echo $topicc; ?>", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

If javascript would print me errors I could probably figure it out or search enough to understand. I've tried many different variations and assigning it to window but still script doesn't wanna work. I finally gave up and moved on in php and im now able call a edit form to replace a comment inside this same div that I want to auto refresh and going to need to pause this script for that too. But once again have no idea of achieving in js without asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

"usertalk" doesn't exist at the time execution so attaching your event handlers is failing. Put your event handlers in the onload function:

```
var chatarea = null;
window.onload=  function() {
    chatarea = document.getElementById('usertalk');
    chatarea.scrollTop = chatarea.scrollHeight;
    chatarea.onfocus=function(){ chatfocus = true; }
    chatarea.onblur=function(){ chatfocus = false; }
}
```

Edit: Didn't realize you're also referencing chatarea in updateChat, define this outside onload's scope as null but only use getElementById after the page has loaded.

Comment: script still not wanting to do anything, if set a new object.getelementbyid('usertalk') instead of using chatarea object and remove my (if chatfocus==false) in my updateActivity function it behaves like it normally does so i believe that fixed the first part of my error.

Comment: Hmm not too sure. Add some alerts to onload and the blur/focus events - which functions are actually firing?

Comment: at first nothing wanted to alert, then i noticed i had a window.onload in the footer of my page. i suppose cant be more then one? commented out footer script and onload alert fired but onfocus and onblur won't alert

Answer (score 0):

i apparently cannot have a onfocus or onblur event on a div area?

after trying every possible way to get those events to work and change a value i didnt quite know how to set as a global without guessing until success, i made a input button to enable/disable my auto updateChat function and set the value in my hidden html form.

also i found useful websites like jshint.com to diagnose possible errors. sorry for being unaware